# How to write a query to get all the column of a table and check if it has a pk or no?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know if a column has a `PK` or no, so I am joining `user_tab_cols` and `user_constraints` to get the type of the query, if a column has the type ='P' the result =1

I am writing a query that select from 
`user_tab_cols` (to join table and column names) ,
`user_constraints`(to get the type of the column and name of the constraint)

```
select tb.table_name,
       tb.column_name,
       case
         when uc.constraint_type ='P' then
          1
         else
          0
       end as PK,
       uc.constraint_name
  from user_tab_cols tb ,user_constraints uc
 where tb.table_name = 'tab1'
   and uc.table_name = tb.table_name
```

My problem is I am getting duplicate columns, I have 10 column for table tab1, I am getting 20 column result(duplicated) I know because I need to join column with both, but if i do that I get only 3 rows( because user_constraints  contain only 3 rows).

How to write the query to get all the column of a table and check if it has a pk or no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use left joins if you want all the columns in the source table, and you're missing the `user_cons_columns` view to get what constraint applies to what column.

Try something like this:

```
select cols.table_name
, cols.column_name
, col_cons.constraint_name
, usr_cons.constraint_type
from user_tab_columns cols
left join user_cons_columns col_cons
  on  col_cons.table_name = cols.table_name
  and col_cons.column_name = cols.column_name
left join user_constraints usr_cons
  on  usr_cons.table_name = cols.table_name
  and usr_cons.constraint_name = col_cons.constraint_name
where cols.table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE'
order by cols.column_name
;
```

You'll get nulls for columns that don't have any type of constraint, and potentially the same constraint name/type for multiple columns if you have composite constraints.

You'll also have multiple rows for some columns if they're subject to multiple constraints, e.g. a (part of a) primary key that also has a foreign key constraint.

```
create table bar (a int primary key);
create table foo (a int, b int, c int
   , constraint foo_pk primary key (a,b)
   , constraint foo_fk foreign key(a) references bar(a));

select cols.table_name
, cols.column_name
, col_cons.constraint_name
, usr_cons.constraint_type
from user_tab_columns cols
left join user_cons_columns col_cons
  on  col_cons.table_name = cols.table_name
  and col_cons.column_name = cols.column_name
left join user_constraints usr_cons
  on  usr_cons.table_name = cols.table_name
  and usr_cons.constraint_name = col_cons.constraint_name
order by table_name, column_name
;
```

```
TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                    CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------
BAR                            A                              SYS_C007382                    P               
FOO                            A                              FOO_FK                         R               
FOO                            A                              FOO_PK                         P               
FOO                            B                              FOO_PK                         P               
FOO                            C
```

Comment: thanks for your query , but how to specific a table name ?

Comment: Just add `where cols.table_name = 'XXX'` after the joins (before the `order by`) like you usually would.

Comment: ah yes , I added `and` it gave me different results . anyway thanks.